# Applying patch to standard python file locally

Tags: python, patch

I am not having any experience in applying patches to python libraries. I found one patch for `difflib.py` from [this site](http://consulting.behnel.de/difflib.cython.patch). I want to apply this patch to standard `difflib.py` file (actually I don't want to modify the standard file). I just want to name it like a new file say `cdifflib.py` after applying patch. can some one please suggest me an easy way of applying patch locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy a new file

```
cp difflib.py cdifflib.py
```

Apply the patch

```
patch -p1 < patch_file
```

Where patch_file is downloaded from [patch site](http://consulting.behnel.de/difflib.cython.patch)

Comment: What is this patch - Is this a seperate program that i need to install? I am using windows7.

Comment: I got the utlity to apply patch on windows. Looks like this patch is not for Python 2.7.3. It failed to apply.

Comment: @Mohsin Run the command in the directory where difflib.py locates.

Comment: Its location is usr/bin/python2.7/difflib.py where pyhton2.7 is not a folder and I cant acess it